# For a cusp modular form of weight $k$, what is remarkable about $y^{k/2}f$ staying bounded as $y\rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: complex-analysis, modular-forms

A holomorphic modular form is said to be a cusp form if its constant Fourier coefficients at the cusps are zero.

In the case of a modular form of weight $k$ for the full modular group $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb Z)$, we can write

$$f(\tau) = F(q) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nq^n,\quad q=e^{2\pi i \tau}, \tau \in \mathbb H$$

Then $f$ is a cusp form if $a_0=0$, because $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb Z) \setminus \mathbb H$ has only one cusp, $\infty$.

According to the [TASI lectures on moonshine](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.00723.pdf), this is equivalent to $y^{k/2}f(x+iy)$ staying bounded as $y\rightarrow \infty$, but it seems that this would be true for any other exponent on $y$. What is special about $k/2$?

Comment: The exponent $k/2$ is relevant because $y^{k/2} |f(x + iy)|$ is invariant under the action of $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$. So this particular power of $y$ is the one you need to put in if you want to do things like integrating over $\operatorname{SL}2(\mathbf{Z}) \backslash \mathbb{H}$ (which is how you define the Petersson scalar product).

Comment: As David said, this invariance also lets us have that $y^{k/2}|f(z)|$ stays bounded over the whole upper half-plane which allows us then to put bounds on $a_n$ (Asymptotic bounds). 

It gives us that $a(n)=O(n^\frac{k}{2})